# Angular 12, rendering dynamically routes in the page error

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to render dynamic routing in Angular but it gives an error.
I want to render the pages according to the route link dynamically.
have a look on a code:
this is archive.component.ts code:

[image]

I want to do this: when user clicks on a link in a home component it takes them to the archive page and the heading there is rendered dynamically on which link user selected.

here are the pictures of it:

[image: this is the error I am getting]

[image: I want to render route dynamically Like that Archive for/ 2021/01]

Comment: I am not sure that your app even builds with those errors there, but the `Object is possibily null` can be fixed by using the optional chaining operator `?`. This way `params.get('year')` becomes `params?.get('year')` (same for the month) and your app should build just fine.